# Why does the picture extend beyond the block?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I specified `max-height: 400px` for the whole `grid`. But child elements are out of bounds, although they should be stretched by height relative to the size of the parent.

[demo](https://codepen.io/Alexxxsander/pen/XWOGedj)

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <img src="https://biggardenfurniture.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/img-placeholder.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  outline: 2px solid royalblue;
  max-height: 400px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid__col {
  height: 100%;  
}

.grid__col:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.grid__col:last-child {
   grid-column: 3 / -1;
 }

.grid__col img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you point out, in any good _grid_ documentation, where it says that a grid tries to fit the child elements in a set vertical height?

Answer (score 0):

Your grid will correctly adjust in size until it reaches a vertical height of 400px. When your grid hits that height it stops growing in height, but not in width. This results your images continuing to grow as they don't respect the containers max height of 400px.

Setting a `max-width` as well will stop the container from growing when it reaches a height of 400px. In this specific case it's a `max-width: 850px;` that does it.

[Example of it working](https://jsfiddle.net/DamageWasTaken/z3uh7qg4/13/)

Comment: But what if the same grid **has to fit** into 400px vertically?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, so a static 400px grid, that doesn't shrink?

Answer (score 0):

use
`.grid__col { height: 190px; (400(maxwidth)/2-10(gap)=190px) }`

instead of
`.grid__col { height: 100%;  }`

Comment: Here you explicitly adapt the height of the cells to the height of the grid. That sort of works, except for the cells that are 2 or 3 rows high.